# How to unit test if all mapstruct targets are really mapped (targeted)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mapstruct

I am thinking about how to verify by a unit test to find out if all targets of the mapstruct mappings are active / in use...

I have the following construct:

```
@Mapper(uses = {DateMapper.class, StateMapper.class})
public abstract class Blah
  implements IDtoContextMapper<SourceEntity, StuffDto> {

  @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")
  @Mapping(source = "someNumber", target = "someStuffNumber")
  @Mapping(target = "status", qualifiedByName = "mapStatus")

  public abstract Blah toDto(
    SourceEntity entity, @Context MappingContext mappingContext);

  @Override
  public Class<StuffDto> getClassOfDto() {
    return StuffDto.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<SourceEntity> getClassOfEntity() {
    return SourceEntity.class;
  }
}
```

And the generated map struct impl looks like:

```
@Override
public StuffDto toDto(SourceEntity entity, MappingContext mappingContext) {
  StuffDto target = mappingContext.getMappedInstance( entity, StuffDto.class );
  if ( target != null ) {
  return target;
  }

  if ( entity == null ) {
  return null;
  }

  StuffDto stuffDto = new StuffDto();

  mappingContext.incrementDepth( entity, StuffDto );

  stuffDto.setId( entity.getId() );
  stuffDto.setStatus( stateMapper.mapStatus( entity.getStatus() ) );
  stuffDto.setSomeStuffNumber( entity.getSomeNumber() );

  mappingContext.updateOccurences( entity, stuffDto );

  return stuffDto;
  }
```

What I am looking for is a simple junit test that verfies that all targets (=all members) of the StuffDto are mapped somehow (by source->target mapping or by qualifiedByName).

Which approach could I begin to try?
Any ideas welcome, I just started to play around :-)

Answer (score -1):

What MapStruct offers is to have compile errors if some target properties is not mapped.

This can be configured through the `ReportingPolicy` on the `Mapper#unmappedTargetPolicy` for the target properties or `Mapper#unmappedSourcePolicy`.

So in your case to make sure that all target properties are mapped you can use

```java
Mapper(uses = {DateMapper.class, StateMapper.class}, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public abstract class Blah
  implements IDtoContextMapper<SourceEntity, StuffDto> {

  @Mapping(source = "someNumber", target = "someStuffNumber")
  @Mapping(target = "status", qualifiedByName = "mapStatus")
  public abstract Blah toDto(
    SourceEntity entity, @Context MappingContext mappingContext);

  @Override
  public Class<StuffDto> getClassOfDto() {
    return StuffDto.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<SourceEntity> getClassOfEntity() {
    return SourceEntity.class;
  }
}
```

Note: I have removed `@Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")` since it is obsolete. MapStruct will implicitly map this property.

Comment: This property can also be set globally for all mappers.
I wrote an article to take this one step further, in some cases with nested objects you still can run into trouble: https://jvwilge.github.io/en/2021/08/31/mapstruct-easyrandom.html

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that all targets are really mapped as the generated code may not set the fields.

Comment: @kylie.zoltan the question was how to validate that they've been defined. Of course that depending on null checksum things might not be set. However, MapStruct can enforce that at least all target properties are defined somehow. To verify whether they are set normal tests should be used